# WordPress: как быстро и удобно вставить много страниц сгенерированных внешним приложением?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть приложение, которое работает локально на моём компьютере. Оно анализирует большую базу данных на много гигабайт и гернерирует несколько десятков HTML-файлов.

Я бы хотел опубликовать эти файлы на сайте под управлением Wordpress. Так чтобы со страницы, где посетитель смотрит файл были доступны все плюшки Wordpress: меню, комментарии, голосовалки, Гугл аналитика и прочее. Как это можно сделать простым способом, не создавая несколько десятков статей вручную?

Моя программа может выдавать текстовые файл. Формат этих файлов можно сделать любым, не обязательно HTML, можно например Markdown или какой-нибудь другой. Надо как то загрузить эти файлы на сайт так, чтобы Wordpress их автоматически преобразовал в статьи.

Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я воспользовался [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). Его оказалось несложно подключить к моей программе и переделки оказались не слишком объёмными.

Из плюсов: в дальнейшем можно будет сделать полноценное манипулирование содержимым сайта, не только создание новых постов но и удаление и обновление постов.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего сделать это так. Создайте папку на сервере, где находится ваш сайт. Скопируйте в неё ваши файлы html. Создайте в ней же файл с любым именем и расширением php. Вставьте код в этот файл:

```
require_once '/var/www/test/wp-load.php'; // Путь к файлу wp-load.php вашего сайта.

$files = glob( '*.html' );

foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    $content = file_get_contents( $file );

    $post_data = [
        'post_title'   => 'File ' . str_replace( '.html', '', $file ),
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
    ];

    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( wp_slash( $post_data ) );

    if ( 0 === $new_post_id ) {
        echo 'Error inserting ' . $file;
    }
}
```

Подробнее здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_insert_post

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можно сделать через wp cli и баш скрипт.
например создать каталог со всеми файлами, сделать так чтоб имя файла соответсвовало имени поста, а контент файла соответсвенно контенту поста и потом залить этот скрипт и выполнить его.
пример для txt файлов

```
#!/bin/bash

files=*.txt

for file in $files
do

title=$(basename $file '.txt')
description=$(cat $file)

wp post create --post_title="$title" --post_content="$description"

done
```